# Overwriting Variable Values from an npm Package in SvelteKit

Tags: css, npm, sveltekit

I am developing a SvelteKit component library that includes a CSS file defining variables for various components, such as background-color and font-family. In the ./dist/index.js file of my library, I export the CSS like this: import './main.css'. In my project, I import it in the +layout.svelte file using the following code: import 'library'.

Initially, everything works as expected, and the colors and fonts are applied correctly. To modify the variable values, I change them inside the :root of my +layout.svelte file, as shown below:

```
<style>
    :root {
        --color-accent: tomato;
    }
</style>
```

Although this approach creates a new :root element with the updated value, it causes some issues. When inspecting the browser devtools, I noticed that the original color is rendered first before the new value takes its place. Strangely, when deploying on Vercel, the new color doesn't seem to render at all. I'm unsure whether the problem lies in my library or in the way I am importing the CSS. How can I ensure that the original value gets properly overwritten?

Image for reference:
[image]

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overwriting them in `:root`, try overwriting them on the html or body element, those come later in the cascade making this more reliable,

```css
:global(html) { 
  --color-accent: tomato
}
```

altough, I would just move these to their own `.css` file and then import it in the layout.svelte component, that way you don't have to mess with `:global` anymore

Comment: Thank you this works! Clarification for anyone in the future if they run into the same issue, `html` seems to have the same specificity as `:root` which might make it unreliable depending on the import order of your stylesheets. Using a selector with a higher specificity such as `body` will ensure that the variables get properly overwritten regardless of the import order.